# Amd A10 7800 lm-sensors

Tags: temperature, lm-sensors

I have a problem regarding lm-sensors, recently i build a computer from an old Acer Aspire t120 with an AMD a10 7800, and i tried to set up monit to monitor the cpu temps, but the problem is lm-sensors cant find any thermal sensors if i  use `sudo sensors-detect`. Is there any other way to monitor the temperature of a CPU ?
I couldnt find the name of the motherboard so i made some pics from the motherboard and the bios.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oo6nb.jpg